# Is there a way to send a short message to all computers in a windows network?

Tags: windows, networking, local-area-network

we have a small network of < 10 machines connected together with a DSL router. i can see the list of machines in 'network' in explorer (windows 7). i tried using the msg command,set the AllowRemoteRPC key in registry for my machine, ran the command prompt with admin privilages as directed here https://superuser.com/questions/217927/msg-command-in-windows-7

am i heading in the wrong direction? does the 'msg' command work only for windows domain controller logins? is there any other way, without installing additional programs , to send messages to machines connected in LAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msg` works on all systems with Terminal Services (which is part of Windows since XP). However, it can only send messages to a single computer, using `msg /server:hostname * Hi!`

- You may need to reboot after changing `AllowRemoteRPC`.
- Also test if it works using `qwinsta /server:hostname`, which uses the same RPC.
- Use this script to call `msg` for each computer:

  ```
  @echo off
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('net view') do (
      set host=%%a
      if "!host:~0,2!"=="\\" (
          msg /server !host:~2! * < message.txt
      )
  )
  ```
- The `*` in *`msg`* examples above can also be a *session name* as displayed by `qwinsta` (use "`console`" to refer to the physically attached monitor/keyboard), or an *user name*.

---

Previous versions of Windows had a NetBIOS-based "Messenger Service", which could send messages to a user, computer, or workgroup. However, this has been removed from Windows Vista and 7. So any suggestions involving "`net send`" should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think the command you want is "net send". I haven't had to use it in years so hopefully it still works as I remember. If you want to hit everyone with it, you'd do something like net send /users Your message here.

Comment: The Messenger Service does not exist in Windows 7.